# How to copy markup - not just plain text - to the clipboard using legacy free JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, selection, clipboard

The complete content of a `<div>`

```
<div id="myElement">
    Mary had a little <b>lamb</b>, its <i>fleece</i> was white as snow. Everywhere that mary went, the lamb was sure to go.
</div>
```

should be copied to the clipboard using this code

```
const copyAll = document.querySelector("myElement");
window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(copyAll);
document.execCommand("Copy");
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

*(For the execCommand to work, the call must be executed via an event listener)*

But only the text-content is copied. Is it possible to copy the markup-code (the `<i>` and `<b>` tags) *without* relying on the legacy firefox clipboard add-on, too?

Answer (score 3):

I used to solve this problem using a fake textarea element copying my custom text into the clipboard.

Something like this should help:

```
const copyText = document.querySelector("myElement").innerHTML;
copyToClipboard(copyText);   


function copyToClipboard(message) {
        let textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.value = message;
        document.body.appendChild(textArea);
        textArea.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(textArea);
    }
```

Comment: Nice detour - if there is no other option, this would be a possible solution. Thank you.