# How to get full clipboard content including formatting and links?

Tags: windows, browser, tinymce, clipboard, wysiwyg

I copied a text from a website and pasted it into a WYSIWYG editor in Magento 2 Enterprise.
The editor automatically detected the right formatting (size, bold, italic...) and even copied links correctly.

If I copy the text into windows notepad instead, then I just get the raw text and all formatting data and links are getting lost.

Is there a way to get the real clipboard data?

---

I would like to SEE the real content of the clipboard for debugging purposes, I did not asked how to copy it, I already have the data in my clipboard. How is the formatting information/ links etc. stored, how can I inspect it?

There is a bug on Magento 2 where certain content copied from a website and pasted into a text form is breaking the "Page Builder" on save, and I need to analyze it.

Where can I paste it to see the full clipboard content? I need a place which does not remove the formatting like notepad does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy markup - not just plain text - to the clipboard using legacy free JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522213/how-to-copy-markup-not-just-plain-text-to-the-clipboard-using-legacy-free-ja)

Comment: @Wimanicesir, no, I would like to SEE the real content of the clipboard for debugging purposes, I did not asked how to copy it, I already have the data in my clipboard. How is the formatting information/ links etc. stored, how can I inspect it?

Comment: 'The real content' is not a description that is clear to me. It looked to me you wanted the html tags included. What do you mean with 'real content' then?

Comment: @Wimanicesir, I would like to see all informations with formatting and link information. For example, how does the WYSIWYG Editor know the formatting/link information if I copy a text from a website, why does it not just paste raw text just like in windows notepad?

Comment: "If you are copy pasting into Notepad from another document application it will paste the text into Notepad and since it is just text it will just convert it to the font currently selected in Notepad with all other formatting removed." Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/notepad-formatting-during-copy-and-paste-from/1b916a8e-36a6-4691-ab75-695c378139f9

Comment: @Wimanicesir, Where can I paste it to see the full clipboard content? I need a place which does not remove the formatting like notepad does.

Comment: I would advise Wordpad

Comment: Wordpad does also remove the original formatting and links.

Comment: Well, Wordpad is still a Rich Text editor and notepad isnt. I can't help you more than tell you the difference :) Good luck on finding another one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. You can paste the content into the tinyMCE editor and then lookup the HTML code. This will show you the full paste content.

It still remains a mystery though and leaves the question open how tinyMCE can access the full content and I still would like to know the magic behind it.

For example I copied the following text of my website:

> Was sind RAL-Farben? RAL ist ein europäisches, weltweit genutztes
> Farbabstimmungssystem, das Farben für Anstriche, Beschichtungen und
> Kunststoffe definiert. Sie haben Fenster oder Türen in ausgefallenen
> Farben und brauchen die passenden Insektenschutz-Profile,
> Alu-Außenfensterbänke oder Zubehörteile? Kein Problem, teilen Sie uns
> einfach den normierten RAL-Farbcode ihrer benötigten Produkte mit und
> wir beschichten diese passend für Ihre Anforderungen.

... then I pasted the text into tinyMCE and if I inspect the HTML code I get this:

```
<div class="pagebuilder-column-group" data-content-type="column-group" data-grid-size="12" data-element="main">
<div class="pagebuilder-column" data-content-type="column" data-appearance="full-height" data-background-images="{}" data-element="main">
<div data-content-type="text" data-appearance="default" data-element="main">
<h2>Was sind RAL-Farben?</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pagebuilder-column" data-content-type="column" data-appearance="full-height" data-background-images="{}" data-element="main">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="pagebuilder-column-group" data-content-type="column-group" data-grid-size="12" data-element="main">
<div class="pagebuilder-column" data-content-type="column" data-appearance="full-height" data-background-images="{}" data-element="main">
<div data-content-type="text" data-appearance="default" data-element="main">
<p>RAL ist ein europäisches, weltweit genutztes Farbabstimmungssystem, das Farben für Anstriche, Beschichtungen und Kunststoffe definiert. Sie haben Fenster oder Türen in ausgefallenen Farben und brauchen die passenden Insektenschutz-Profile, Alu-Außenfensterbänke oder Zubehörteile? Kein Problem, teilen Sie uns einfach den normierten RAL-Farbcode ihrer benötigten Produkte mit und wir beschichten diese passend für Ihre Anforderungen.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Every rich text editor has this option even wordpad :) Glad you found a solution :)

Comment: Sorry, I double checked and you are right. Wordpad doesn't support it out of the box. You can however add an addon for it but an other text editor will do the same :)

Comment: tinyMCE also strips out many classes and styling by default. There is an app called InsideClipboard that shows you all different versions of the clipboard including the HTML one.